# Count elements in 1st array less than or equal than elements in 2nd array python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have an array `A`of 21381120 elements ranking from [0,1]. I need to construct a new array `B` in which the element `i` contains the number of elements in A less than or equal than `A[i]`.

My attempt:

```
A = np.random.random(10000) # for reproducibility
g = np.sort(A)
B = [np.sum(g<=element) for element in A]
```

I am still using a `for loop`, taking too much time. Since I have to do this several times I was wondering if exists a better way to do it.

EDIT

I gave an example of the array A for reproducibility. This does what is expected to. But I need it to be faster (for arrays having `2e9` elements).

For instance if:

```
A = [0.1,0.01,0.3,0.5,1]
```

I expect the output to be

```
B = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: There, I edited the question, maybe that clarifies what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use binary search to speed up searching in a sorted array.  [Binary search in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

```
A = np.random.rand(10000) # for reproducibility
g = np.sort(A)
B = [np.searchsorted(g, element) for element in A]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks,. Even for the arrays of  tens of millions of elements, this doesn't take more than a minute.

Comment: Glad to help. Binary search time complexity is O(logn) and before you were using linear search(time complexity O(n))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sorting is the way to go because in a sorted array `A`, the number of elements less than or equal to `A[i]` is *almost* `i + 1`.

However, if an element is repeated, you'll have to look at the nearest element that's to the right of `A[i]`:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]
           ^^^^^ A[3] == A[4] == A[5]
```

Here, the number of elements `<= A[3]` is `3 + <number of repeated 4's>`. Maybe you could roll your own sorting algorithm that would keep track of such repetitions. Or count the repetitions before sorting the array.

Then the final formula would be:

```
N(<= A[k]) = k + <number of elements equal to A[k]>
```

So the speed of your code would mainly depend on the speed of the sorting algorithm.